# Is it possible for homepage in Twentyseventeen theme to look like a standard page?

Tags: frontpage

I'm using the Twentyseventeen theme and I would like the home page to be a regular page, rather than the default style for the theme, which is a very large image and an arrow down to allow you to get to the content. I have clicked on the settings for the homepage to display a static page and chosen the page I want to be on the homepage but it automatically defaults to then displaying it as the particular home page style for this theme. I can see how that's a good look but I think my client would prefer it to look like a regular page, the same as other pages on the site. Is there a way to change the code so that the home page simply displays a page?
Many thanks

Comment: You want different layout for home page?

Comment: Remove the header image in customizer

Comment: Thanks for comments. Yes, I'd like a different layout for the home page. I would still like to have a header image for use on every page of the website so I have a problem if I remove it completely from the customizer. I just want to be able to stop the full screen display that happens automatically with Twentyseventeen front page.